# Serial Connection ATMEGA328p

Tags: c, arduino, avr, uart, atmega

I wrote up a function to connect via UART and print a string for debugging purposes. But my logic does not add up somehow... I see the line "Random Number" printed in the console but blazingly fast... no matter what I add for a _delay_ms value, it is not usable. Did I miss out on anything?

Why is my delay function not having any influence on the output on the serial terminal?

```
void initUSART(void) {

    #define BAUDRATE ((F_CPU) / (BAUD * 8UL)-1) // Set Baud Rate Value for UBRR

    // Set register
    UBRR0H = (BAUDRATE >> 8);
    UBRR0L = BAUDRATE;
    UCSR0A |= (1 << U2X0);  
    // Enable USART transmitter and receiver
    UCSR0B = (1 << TXEN0) | (1 << RXEN0);
    // Set 8 data bits and 1 stop bit
    UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);
}

void transmitByte(uint8_t data) {
    // Wait for empty transmit buffer
    loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, UDRE0);
    UDR0 = data;
}

void printString(const char myString[]) {
    uint8_t i = 0;
    while (myString[i]) {
        transmitByte(myString[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    setup();    
    randomSeed(adcRead(0));

    while (1) 
    {   
        printString("Random Number:\n");
        _delay_ms(100000);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

When I use `\r\n`at the end of the string, the output gets really strange:

[image]

When I try this test code everything works as expected, the LED blinks every second. I really don't see where the difference is, as it is the same function.

```
                                                       /* Blinker Demo */

// ------- Preamble -------- //
#include <avr/io.h>                        /* Defines pins, ports, etc */
#include <util/delay.h>                     /* Functions to waste time */


int main(void) {

  // -------- Inits --------- //
  DDRB |= 0b00000001;            /* Data Direction Register B:
                                   writing a one to the bit
                                   enables output. */

  // ------ Event loop ------ //
  while (1) {

    PORTB = 0b00000001;          /* Turn on first LED bit/pin in PORTB */
    _delay_ms(1000);                                           /* wait */

    PORTB = 0b00000000;          /* Turn off all B pins, including LED */
    _delay_ms(1000);                                           /* wait */

  }                                                  /* End event loop */
  return 0;                            /* This line is never reached */
}
```

Comment: would you paste the output what you get?, is last two bytes are garbage value?

Comment: The output I get is in the screenshot on the right (the serial terminal)

Comment: I think I don't get it. Where do you mena?

Comment: changed the lines in transmitByte() but did not have any effect

Comment: Yeah, realized it is not the problem

Comment: Could be the case your stop bits are different size on the transmitting and the receiving side. Make sure all of the settings are synchronized

Comment: Hmmm unfortunately not

Comment: Do you have `F_CPU` defined(properly)? http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrlibcreferencemanual/group__util__delay_1gad22e7a36b80e2f917324dc43a425e9d3.html

Comment: yep I set it to #define F_CPU 1000000

Comment: Is it the true frequency? 1MHz?

Comment: Yep the default frequency of my ATMEGA

Comment: *The maximal possible delay is 262.14 ms / F_CPU in MHz.*. So your maximum delay is 262ms

Comment: hm... I am a bit surprised, I cannot set the delay to a time I want to?

Comment: This is what documentation tells.

Comment: But you forgot to read further in the documentation of _delay_ms, where it says:  "If the avr-gcc toolchain has __builtin_avr_delay_cycles(unsigned long) support, maximal possible delay is 4294967.295 ms/ F_CPU in MHz. For values greater than the maximal possible delay, overflows results in no delay i.e., 0ms."

Comment: How does the Arduino handles this.. i remember when I used Serial.Read that output appeared around every second on the terminal

Comment: According to [this](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrlibcreferencemanual/group__util__delay_1gad22e7a36b80e2f917324dc43a425e9d3.html), _delay_ms() should work up to 6.5535 seconds. However, starting with delays higher than 262.14 ms, the resolution is decreased to 1/10ms. And you could always wrap _delay_ms() in another function that loops it multiples of 100ms for example to get higher any delay of your choice.